# Batch file to locate USB drive used

Tags: batch-file, syntax, usb, drive

Hello I wanted to practice coding by making a batch file to automate antivirus downloads for my elderly family members. I had it working yesterday but it seems I accidentally broke it and now it says it cant parse the loop on the first line. Its supposed to locate the drive letter of the USB and run malwarebytes from the usb stick. Here is my code:

```
@echo off

for %%a in (d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do vol %%a: 2>nul |find "Transcend" >nul && set drv=%%a:
%drv%

if exist "c:\program files (x86)\Malwarebytes Anti-Malware\mbam.exe" ( 

) else (

%drv%\mbam-setup-2.2.1.1043 /silent /NORESTART

sleep 120

)

"c:\program files (x86)\Malwarebytes Anti-Malware\mbam.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to detect if your USB is connected or not !

This code is inspired by **[Hackoo_Cleanings_Tools.bat](http://pastebin.com/j0U5fDwn)** :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" ^|find /i ":"') do (Set MyUSB=%%i)
cls
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set _drive=%MyUSB%
If Exist !_drive! (
cls
echo.
echo           #########################################################
echo                        Your usb key is connected as !_drive!
echo           #########################################################
echo.
pause
Cls
Explorer "!_drive!\"
) ELSE (
cls
color 0C
echo.
echo           #########################################################
echo                         Your usb key is not detected
echo           #########################################################
echo.
pause
)
```

Comment: im looking for the batch file to locate the drive letter and install programs from it not really if its connected or not. thanks for the response though